# How to reason across equality proofs?

Tags: coq

Say I have a slightly different definition of addition, and a slightly different definition of vector appending:

```
From Coq Require Import Vector.

Definition myAddNat a b := nat_rect _ b (fun _ p => S p) a.

Theorem rewrite_myAddNat a b : myAddNat a b = (a + b)%nat.
Proof.
  induction a.
  { reflexivity. }
  {
    simpl.
    congruence.
  }
Defined.

Definition myAppend T m n : Vector.t T m -> Vector.t T n -> Vector.t T (myAddNat m n).
  rewrite rewrite_myAddNat.
  apply Vector.append.
Defined.
```

I would like to be able to prove the following:

```
Theorem myAppend_cons_1 T m n h a b :
    myAppend T (S m) n (cons T h m a) b =
    cons T h (myAddNat m n) (myAppend T m n a b).
Proof.
  induction a.
  { reflexivity. }
  {
    simpl.
    unfold myAppend.
    (* stuck! *)
  }
Abort.
```

I end up stuck on two terms that are very close to each other, except they each have an equality cast in a different position that I am not sure how to handle.

I have considered changing my theorem statement to:

```
Theorem myAppend_cons T m n h a b :
    existT _ _ (myAppend T (S m) n (cons T h m a) b) =
    existT _ _ (cons T h (myAddNat m n) (myAppend T m n a b)).
```

so as to be able to temporarily make the two sides of the equation have a different type, but have not been able to make much more progress on the proof.

So:

1) Is there a nice way to prove either theorem

or,

2) Should I write `myAppend` in a different way that will make my life easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick answer:

```
Theorem myAppend_cons_1 T m n h a b :
    myAppend T (S m) n (cons T h m a) b =
    cons T h (myAddNat m n) (myAppend T m n a b).
Proof.
  unfold myAppend, eq_rect_r; simpl.
  rewrite !eq_trans_refl_l, !eq_sym_map_distr.
  now destruct (eq_sym _).
Qed.
```

Comment: Ah! I had been unlucky in abstracting over `eq_sym`, guess it was simpler than what I thought! Thanks!